# Inheriting from bad template instantiations in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overriding, instantiation

Consider the following code:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo operator+(const Foo &rhs) const;
    // notice lack of: Foo operator*(const Foo &rhs) const;
};

template <class T>
struct Bar
{
    T x, y;
    T add() const { return x + y; }
    T mul() const { return x * y; }
};
```

I have two questions:

1. Can I inherit from `Bar<Foo>` and override `mul()` to something meaningful?
2. Can I inherit from `Bar<Foo>` without overriding `mul()` if I never use `mul()` anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. sure
2. sure

Templates are really a kind of smart preprocessor, they're not compiled. If you don't use something, you can write complete (syntactically correct) rubbish, i.e you may inherit from

```
template <class T>
struct Bar
{
    T x, y;
    T add() const { return x + y; }
    T mul() const { return x.who cares what-s in here; }
};
```

P.S. since your + operator is used in a const function, it should be declared as const too.

*EDIT*: OK, not all compilers support this, here's one that compiles with gcc:

```
template <class T>
struct Bar
{
    T x, y;
    T add() const { return x + y; }
    T mul() const { T::was_brillig & T::he::slith(y.toves).WTF?!0:-0; }
};
```

Comment: you're right about the `const`, I was just quickly typing something up without much thought (it's not actual code)

Comment: Although that example won't compile; as you say, the uninstantiated function must still be syntactically correct.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, added one that will

Answer (score 3):

1. `Bar<Foo>::mul()` isn't a virtual function, so it cannot be overridden.
2. Yes, if you don't use a template member function then it does not get instantiated and you don't get any errors that would result from instantiating it.

You can *hide* `Bar<Foo>::mul()` by providing a function of the same signature in a subclass, and because of *2*, `Bar<Foo>::mul()` won't be instantiated. However this is probably not a good practice. Readers are likely to get confused about the hiding vs. overriding, and there's not much benefit to doing this over simply using a different function name and never using `mul()`, or providing an explicit specialization of Bar for Foo.

Comment: A member function does not have to be virtual to be overridden. It only needs to be virtual if you are using polymorphism (i.e. calling it from a pointer to a base class).

Comment: @Matt If the function is not virtual then it's not being overridden, it's being hidden.

Comment: You can call it whatever you want, that is just a matter of semantics.

Comment: @Matt no it's not, the base class's version still exists. Please read the standard on this issue.

Comment: @SethCarnegie since when did overriding mean overwriting? The English word 'override' does not imply that what is overridden no longer exists.

Comment: @Matt this isn't English, it's C++, and the standard defines certain terms to mean certain things within C++.

Comment: @SethCarnegie that is why I said it is just semantics. I don't have to refer to things the way the standard says if I don't want to as long as it still makes sense. I can call member functions methods, but I cannot call pointers references (that would cause confusion). In this case, 'override' causes no confusion because `mul()` is not virtual.

Comment: @Matt why not use the word hide? It would cause _even less confusion_. Overriding implies that when you use the function through a pointer/reference to the base class, it will use the "overridden" version. Hiding does not do that.

Comment: @SethCarnegie because at that moment I was not thinking "What does the C++ standard call overriding in this specific case?"